# I'm getting a path error in OpenCV, but all the files are in the same folder

Tags: python, opencv

When I try to run the following code as KernelTesting.py:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('TestImageNov7th.fits')
kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
newimg = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)
cv2.imwrite('NewImageNov23rd.fits', newimg)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KernelTesting.py", line 6, in <module>
    newimg = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-b4ibzwe2/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/filter.dispatch.cpp:1530: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'filter2D'
```

The image and the code are both stored in the same folder. I don't recognize and can't locate the path mentioned in the error message. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the images in the same folder as your script? If not, you need to provide the path to your images. Also check spelling?  I do not see fits as a format that OpenCV can read at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56. Has that changed?

Comment: I don't see a path error

Comment: Thanks fmw42, that's my problem. Do you know of any programs that can convolve kernels with fits images?

Comment: Did you try the same code with any other image? Since when I use `.png` the code works fine.